# Async/Await: Understanding problem with Async / Await

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await, node-modules

I am using async/await. I want to display my data that i have retrieved from readable stream first and then display the corresponding message;

here is my code:

```
var stream = async function (){
           var myStream =  fs.createReadStream(__dirname+"/someText.txt",'utf8');

            await myStream.on('data', (chunk)=>{
             console.log(chunk)// I want to display this first
        }) 
 }

stream()

console.log('listening') // and then move on to display this one
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

streams listeners are not promises, you should not `await` on `myStream.on('data')`. You can do it, but it will resolve immediately.

Wrap the stream listener in a `Promise` and await it, for this you can use [once](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_events_once_emitter_name)

```
const { once } = require('events');

var stream = async function (){
   var myStream =  fs.createReadStream(__dirname+"/someText.txt",'utf8');

    myStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
       console.log(chunk)// I want to display this first
    });

    // Wait until everything has been read
    // Or an error has been triggered
    await once(myStream, 'close'); 
}

(async() => {
  await stream(); // await can only be used in `async` function
  console.log('listening');
})().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: I got the idea. I have confusion about the syntax at the end lines. async starts with Parentheses, i dont understand this one. And Parenthesis at the end of its curly bracket

//this one here -> (async() => {
  await stream(); // await can only be used in `async` function
  console.log('listening');
})()//<-this one here.catch(console.error);